# Why isn't gitignore not working on recursive files?

Tags: git

I am trying to ignore all the subdirectories and files in those sub directories inside a folder names client_store_assets

The sub directories in the client_store_assets, has different names in it.

I have tried adding /client_store_assets/*  and  /client_store_assets/*/* to gitignore and they both didn't work

Does anyone know how to fix this issues?

Here is an example of my directory structure. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
client_store_assets
     ralph_ice_cream
        store_settings.php
     tonys_pizza
         store_settings.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading slash.

```
client_store_assets/
```

If you have already staged those files you will need to remove them with `git rm --cached <filename>`